# how to display image from rss

Tags: rss, thumbnails

i'have added thumbnail image to Rss of my blog and I'm using this code to display the rss in another website .

please guide me how to add image thumbnail to this code ...

see the result at : [Pmanagers.org](http://pmanagers.org)

```
<?php // Get RSS Feed(s)
include_once( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/feed.php' );

// Get a SimplePie feed object from the specified feed source.
$rss = fetch_feed( 'http://pmanagers.org/blog/feed/' );
$maxitems = 0;
if ( ! is_wp_error( $rss ) ) :
    $maxitems = $rss->get_item_quantity( 6 ); 
    $rss_items = $rss->get_items( 0, $maxitems );
endif;
?>
<div class="headwrp">
<h4>Latest Blog posts</h4>
</div>
<ul>
<?php if ( $maxitems == 0 ) : ?>
        <li><?php _e( 'No items', 'my-text-domain' ); ?></li>
    <?php else : ?>
        <?php // Loop through each feed item and display each item as a hyperlink. ?>
<div class=" owl-carousel">
        <?php foreach ( $rss_items as $item ) : ?>
<div class="item">
            <li id="news-single">

                <a href="<?php echo esc_url( $item->get_permalink() ); ?>"     target="_blank"
                    title="<?php printf( __( 'Posted %s', 'my-text-domain' ), $item->get_date('j F Y | g:i a') ); ?>">
                <?php echo esc_html( $item->get_title() ); ?>
            </a>
        </li>
</div>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Displaying images from external RSS feeds?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2982/displaying-images-from-external-rss-feeds)

Answer (score 1):

Try using the_post_thumbnail WP function, inside your `<li id="news-single">` markup definition:

```
        <li id="news-single">

            <a href="<?php echo esc_url( $item->get_permalink() ); ?>" target="_blank" title="<?php printf( __( 'Posted %s', 'my-text-domain' ), $item->get_date('j F Y | g:i a') ); ?>">
            <?php echo esc_html( $item->get_title() ); ?>
            </a>

            <?php
            // This is the piece of code that you should add:
            // You first need to check if the post has a thumbnail assigned.
            if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                the_post_thumbnail();
            } 
            ?>

        </li>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: hello Capiedge  , I've used this but won't work :(

Comment: Are you sure that the posts has a post_thumbnail declared?

Comment: yes ,I'm sure you can see yourself at :  http://pmanagers.org/blog/feed/

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code

```
function get_first_image_url($html)
{
    if (preg_match('/<img.+?src="(.+?)"/', $html, $matches)) {
        return $matches[1];
    }
    else return 'url_of_default_image_if_post_has_no_img_tags.jpg';
}
```

and then add the line:

```
<?php echo '<img src="' .get_first_image_url($item->get_content()). '"/>'; ?>
```

you can find the source code [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/using-simplepie-to-take-only-first-image-from-rss-feed/6553/6)